# SCSS paths in angular library

Tags: angular, sass, storybook, angular-library, ng-packagr

I am creating angular library, and I have some scss files in `my-lib/src/styles` and I include those files in component scss files. For instance:

```
@import 'src/styles/_tokens.scss';
```

When I build the library with `ng build` it is working fine, but when I run the `storybook` it cannot find path. In `storybook` it works if I put path from the workspace root folder to the scss file, for instance:

```
@import '/projects/my-lib/src/styles/_tokens.scss';
```

So one path works for `ng build`, another one for `storybook`. The question is how can I make it to work for both?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, I need to use relative paths inside scss files and it will work everywhere. There is also `styleIncludePaths` in `ng-package.json` but it does not seem to work.

Also not just in scss files but in ts files too we need to use relative imports because absolute imports are not working when library is published and installed in other application. Basically if creating angular library relative imports are a must everywhere.